# IndexedBD select objects from upper to lower?

Tags: javascript, database, html, select, indexeddb

For example:

```
const customerData = [
  { id: 444, name: "Bill", age: 35, email: "bill@company.com" },
  { id: 5555, name: "Donna", age: 32, email: "donna@home.org" },
  { id: 666, name: "Cat", age: 2, email: "cat@home.org" },
  { id: 888, name: "Gandalf", age: 21000, email: "gandalf@home.org" }
];

function getDataByRange(db, table, index, lower, upper, fun){

    var data = [];
    var tx = db.transaction(table, "readonly");
    var store = tx.objectStore(table);
    var index = store.index(index);

    var boundKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(lower, upper, false, false);

    var request = index.openCursor(boundKeyRange);
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var cursor = request.result;
        if (cursor) {
            data.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            fun(data);
        }
    };
}
```

How to get next results: Gandalf, Bill, Donna, Cat?

Now I get something like: Cat,Donna, Bill, Gandalf.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [openCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.openCursor) method accepts two arguments. The second argument is optional and specifies the direction of the cursor. Because it is optional, you rarely see the second argument specified in example code, so maybe that is why it is confusing.

There are four possible direction values: next, prev, nextUnique, and prevUnique. You specify the argument as a string. next is the implied default argument.

So, use `openCursor(boundKeyRange, 'prev')` to iterate in reverse.